# Identifying relative size of overlapping groups based on information in 2 vectors

Tags: r, vector, intersect

I am working with very messy family data, in that it is possible for kids to be grouped with multiple families. The data is structured as follows:

```
famid <- c("A","A","B","C","C","D","D")
kidid <- c("1","2","1","3","4","4","5")
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(famid, kidid))
```

I want to identify which families I can drop, based on the criteria that all of the kids in that family are grouped together in another, larger, family.

For example, Family A contains Kid 1 and Kid 2. Family B contains Kid 1. Because Family B is entirely contained within Family A, I want to drop Family B.

Alternatively, Family C contains Kid 3 and Kid 4. Family D contains Kid 4 and Kid 5. Neither family is entirely contained within the other, so I do not want to drop either for the time being.

In my data there can be up to 6 families per kid and up to 8 kids per family. There are thousands of families and thousands of kids.

I have tried addressing this by creating a very wide data.frame with one row per student, with columns for each family the kid is associated with, each sibling in each family that the kid is associated with, and an additional column (`sibgrp`) for each associated family that concatenates all siblings together. But when I tried to search for individual siblings within the concatenated string, I found I didn't know how to do this -- `grepl` won't take a vector as the pattern argument.

I then started to look into intersect and similar functions, but those compare entire vectors to each other, not observations within a vector to other observations within that vector. (Meaning -- I can't look for the intersections between character string `df[1,2]` and character string `df[1,3]`. Intersect instead identifies the intersections between `df[2]` and `df[3]`).

I tried to change my thinking to accommodate this approach, so that I could compare vectors of siblings to each other, assuming that I know already that at least one sibling is shared. I could not figure out how to even begin doing this, given how many different families there are, and how many are not related to each other by even one shared kid.

What am I missing here? Would very much appreciate any feedback. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function can also be used for doing the task. It returns a character vector containing the names of the families that can be removed.

```
test_function <- function(dataset){

## split the kidid on the basis of famid
kids_family <- split.default(dataset[['kidid']],f = dataset[['famid']])

family <- names(kids_family)

## This function generates all the possible combinations if we select any two families from family
combn_family <- combn(family,2)

family_removed <- character(0)
apply(combn_family,MARGIN = 2, function(x){

  if (length(setdiff(kids_family[[x[1]]],kids_family[[x[2]]])) == 0)
    family_removed <<- c(family_removed,x[1])
  else if (length(setdiff(kids_family[[x[2]]],kids_family[[x[1]]])) == 0)
    family_removed <<- c(family_removed,x[2])

})

return (family_removed)
}
> df <- data.frame(famid = c("A","A","B","C","C","D","D", "E", "E", "E", "F", "F"),
+                  kidid = c(1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 7, 9))
> test_function(df)
[1] "B" "F"
```

Comment: Could you please detail your solution?

Comment: @VincentBonhomme That's what I was asking to do.

Comment: Thanks, @KunalPuri. I'm off work for the weekend but will try this out first thing tomorrow. It looks like a very elegant solution, though I must admit I don't totally understand its inner workings.

Comment: @szw You can always come back and share your queries on this post.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried around `setdiff` with no chance. I came and post this laborious solution in the hope there is a better way.

```
# dependencies for melting tables and handling data.frames
require(reshape2)
require(dplyr)


# I have added two more cases to your data.frame
# kidid is passed as numeric (with quoted would have been changed to vector by default)
df <- data.frame(famid = c("A","A","B","C","C","D","D", "E", "E", "E", "F", "F"),
                 kidid = c(1, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 7, 9))

# let's have a look to it
df
famid kidid
1      A     1
2      A     2
3      B     1
4      C     3
5      C     4
6      D     4
7      D     5
8      E     7
9      E     8
10     E     9
11     F     7
12     F     9

# we build a contingency table
m <- table(df$famid, df$kidid)

# a family A only contains a family B, if A has all the elements of B, 
# and at least one that B doesnt have
m

  1 2 3 4 5 7 8 9
A 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
B 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
C 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
D 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
E 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
F 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1

# an helper function to implement that and return a friendly data.frame
family_contained <- function(m){
  res <- list()
  for (i in 1:nrow(m))
    # for each line in m, we calculate the difference to all other lines
    res[[i]] <- t(apply(m[-i, ], 1, function(row) m[i, ] - row))
  # here we test if all values are 0+ (ie if the selected family has all element of the other)
  # and if at least one is >=1 (ie if the selected family has at least one element that the other doesnt have)
  tab <- sapply(res, function(m) apply(m, 1,  function(x) all(x>=0) & any(x>=1)))
  # we format it as a table to have nice names
  tab %>% as.table() %>% 
    # we melt it into a data.frame
    melt()  %>% 
    # only select TRUE and get rid of this column
    filter(value) %>% select(-value) %>% 
    # to make things clear we name columns
    `colnames<-`(c("this_family_is_contained", "this_family_contains"))
}

family_contained(m)
# this_family_is_contained this_family_contains
# 1           B               A
# 2           F               E

# finally you can filter them with
filter(df, !(famid %in% family_contained(m)$this_family_is_contained))
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this so thoroughly, @VincentBonhomme